# Orchard CMS - Custom Content Type and full layout control of each field on the front-end

Tags: razor, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I am using Orchard v.1.9.2.0. I made a custom Content Definition called Event Page. Here is a screen shot of the Fields and Parts I created for it:

[image]

My question is... I want to be able to control the "Event Detail Page" layout, so that I can place each of these fields exactly where I want to place them.

Right now, by default, Content.cshtml has `@Display(Model.Content)` and writes out all of these fields out to the page on its own.

I thought I can achieve this with the Layouts feature, but I don't see these newly defined fields in the layout editor. I am now thinking, can I just display each of these fields directly into content.cshtml?

For example, in my custom Content Type, I have a field called Event Logo, I tried using `@Display(Model.Content.EventPage.EventLogo)`, however all it renders is `Orchard.MediaLibrary.Fields.MediaLibraryPickerField` in plain text to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, fields should be in a toolbox when you create/edit Event Page (if you create layout that fields don't be shown in the toolbox).

Using fields in layout make sence if you are using field values (or planning use it) in different places (summary view, projection). Otherwise it will be simpler to use layout elements (like html, image, paragraph, etc.)

If you have certain page structure which only that fields are used in. It probably be simpler to configurate positions through placement.info (that you will have opportunity to modify structure for all Event Page in one place and content managers will be spared of building the correct page structure).

You can include fields to any local zone through placement.info

```
<Match ContentType="EventPage">
<Match DisplayType="Detail">
  <Place Fields_Common_Text-LatestNew="LatestNewsAndRaceResultLocalZoneName:1"
         Fields_Common_Text-RaceResults="LatestNewsAndRaceResultLocalZoneName:2"
         Fields_MediaLibraryPicker-EventLogo="OtherLocalZoneName:1"
         />
</Match>
</Match>
```

and then create alternate `Content-EventPage.Detail.cshtml` (by copying and renaming `Content.cshtml`).
Finally inside `Content-EventPage.Detail.cshtml` you can use

```
@Display(Model.LatestNewsAndRaceResultLocalZoneName)
@Display(Model.OtherLocalZoneName)
```

Comment: I will try this out later and see if it works out for me, thanks. I wasn't sure how to use placement.info, so thanks for guiding me